# How to export a device configuaration in Gns3

Tags: cisco, gns3

I have A Gns3 topology and i try to save my configurations to a txt file in my desktop.
I tried the  [Tools] > [Import/Export node config] in the menu,[Export configs to a directory] but it only saves my VPCs configurations. The devices i try to save are mostly cisco iosv routers. Any suggestions?